# AngularJs ui-router has error : http 404

Tags: angularjs

I have an issues of assigning controller using angularJs. Following is what I have:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('core', {
            abstract:   true,
            template:   '<ui-view ></ui-view>',
            cache:      'false',
            controller: 'CoreController as core',
            data:       {
                AuthRequired: true
            }

        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({events: true});
})
```

and my html:

```
 <base href="/" />
```

url :http://localhost:9000/customer

However,when enI receiving an error on console:
HTTP 404 ; not found;

Comment: Where are you stating that I want to go to state `core` ? Either change your url to http://localhost:9000/customer#core and provide `url: '/core'` property OR `use $state.go('core')` when your application module starts running.

Comment: I know what you mean. and has some changes:  ".state('workbench.index', { url:   '/workbench',}....)" ; and ‘#’is disappear，but errors is still happen.  ps:Please ignore my broken English.